# Azure Service bus Subscription disable auto delete

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I have created a Subscription for Topic, Initially, I have created with auto-delete option. Now I want to change it to Never auto-delete.

Comment: I think directly updating this property isn't supported, and you'll need to create a new subscription with the desired auto-delete setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about "Auto Delete on Idle" setting for the Subscription, you can change it through Portal.

Go to Subscription > Expand Settings (on the right hand side) > Click "change" on "Auto-delete" setting > Check the checkbox for "Never auto-delete".

[image]

Comment: Yup, I have figured it out. Thank you very much for your answer